# Лучшее средство для написания игр под Android

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Собираюсь писать код под Android. Знаю язык Java. Какой движок есть? Кроме Unity, так-как там не используется Java.

```
public Help helpMe() {
   System.out.println("Help me, please!");
   return new Help();
}
```

Comment: легче будет подучить c# и клепать игры на юнити, чем лезть в андроид ради них :)

Comment: **[LIBgdx](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibGDX)** для 2d-3d под android..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для старта могу посоветовать кросплатформенный движок [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/). Он хорош для написать 2d игр для мобильных платформ (там используется Lua, но какая разница, ЯП всего лишь инструмент).
Для более серьезных проектов уже нужно брать [Libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) (java) или [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) (C++) или все таки [Unity](https://unity3d.com/ru) (C#).
В качестве эксперимента пробовал для мобильных платформ писать на связке PhoneGap + PhaserJS (первое упаковывает веб приложение в мобильное, второе JS библиотека для игр), но показалось слишком затратной идеей. 
**В общем** советую начать с CoronaSDK, а дальше один из выше перечисленных движков, но Cocos2d-x менее приоритетный, т.к. нет поддержки 3d.